# My Inno Setup script creates two Desktop Icons

Tags: inno-setup

I am using the following lines to create icons:

```
Name: "{group}\<PRODUCTNAME>"; Filename: "{app}\<PRODUCTEXENAME>"
Name: "{group}\<PRODUCTNAME> (Log Mode)"; Filename: "{app}\<PRODUCTEXENAME>"; Parameters: "/log"
Name: "{group}\{cm:ProgramOnTheWeb,<PRODUCTNAME>}"; Filename: "{app}\<PRODUCTNAME>.url"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,<PRODUCTNAME>}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"

Name: "{userdesktop}\<PRODUCTNAME>"; Filename: "{app}\<PRODUCTEXENAME>";
Name: "{commondesktop}\<PRODUCTNAME>"; Filename: "{app}\<PRODUCTEXENAME>"; WorkingDir: "{app}"
Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\<PRODUCTNAME>"; Filename: "{app}\<PRODUCTEXENAME>";WorkingDir:"{app}"
```

I guess I just did a mistake where I place a desktop icon twice. 
Does anybody see where my mistake is?

Comment: Icons to be displayed on desktop are taken from the *all users* profile desktop (`{commondesktop}`) and from the current user's desktop (`{userdesktop}`) directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create 1 icon for Current User `{userdesktop}` and 1 icon for All Users `{commondesktop}`. After installation if you would log on to another account you would see only `{commondesktop}` one.

You should choose only 1 of those 2, which corresponds to your application behavior. If your application should work for every user on the computer, you should choose the `{commondesktop}`, but if it is intended to work only for User who installed the application, you should choose `{userdesktop}`.